# How do I make an Illustrator script that makes a specific layer invisible?

Tags: layer, adobe-illustrator, invisible

I have no experience in programming, so I apologize for being new to everything.

I am trying to make a simple Illustrator script that a specifically named layer (for example, "text") in all open files invisible.
It would also be nice if it could save all the files in the end.

**simple example**
[image: simple example]

If anyone can help, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is script to invisible layer name ="text" and save after edit:

```
for(var i=0;i<app.documents.length;i++)
{
        var oDoc=app.documents[i];
        for(var j=0;j<oDoc.layers.length; j++)
        {
            if(oDoc.layers[j].name=="text")
            {
                oDoc.layers[j].visible=false;
             }
       }
      oDoc.save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This saves so much time for me! :) 
For some reason, only the top (active) file gets saved (instead of all of the open files) so I merged it with a different script and it works beautifully!

Deleted "oDoc.save();" and copied and pasted the script from here -> https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/save-all-command/m-p/8783487